# F# use managed DLL with included .so file

Tags: macos, .net-core, f#, mono

I am trying to use a 3rd party managed DLL that wraps an unmanaged a `.so` and I can't figure out how to avoid the `System.DllNotFoundException` on Mac OS.

This library has two files

- `managed_wraper.dll`
- `unmanaged_library.so`

If I am on a linux box putting the `.so` and the DLL in the output folder works, on Mac OS that does not work. I also can't get any platform working with Jupyter.

**What have I tried for the CLI app on Mac OS**

- Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH, DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
- http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/loading-native-dlls-in-fsharp-interactive.html
- Too many SO pages to link here
- Putting the `.so` in various places `~/Library`, `current directory`, `output directory`

I don't even know where to start with Jupyter, I can get it to find the DLL with `#r`, but when the DLL tries to find the `.so` it all comes crashing down.

**Software Versions**

- Mac OS 10.14.6
- .NET 2.1.401 - Mac
- jupyter core 4.6.1, jupyter-notebook : 6.0.2

Comment: Do you have the associated .dylib file for macos? Macos uses dylibs, not so or dll files, so your library needs to bundle one if you want to be able to use the native library on macos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I dislike computers :) So here is what worked for CLI Apps

**Linux CLI**
Copy the `DLL` and the `.so` into the output folder

**Mac OS CLI**
I had to rename the `.so` to `.dylib`
You can then:

1. Copy the the wrapper DLL and `libray.so` to the output folder and **rename** the `library.so`to `library.dylib`
2. Rename `libray.so` to `library.dylib` and set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

In either case you must copy the wrapper DLL to the output folder. Maybe `dotnet` only loads `.dylib` but I have seen where you can use `.so` files on Mac OS. Please someone enlighten me